# Spring - Mass problem solved with scilab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I need to solve a spring - mass problem with a numerical method in scilab using this differential equation $$\frac{d^2x}{d t^{2}} + \frac{k}{m} x = 0$$ with these initial values: $$k = 1 , m = 1 , x_0=1,x'(0) = 0 m/s$$

[image: spring-mass]

what I have done:

```
function ydot=f(t, y)
    k=1
    m=1
    ydot(1) = y(2);
    ydot(2) = k/m*y(1);
endfunction
y0 = [10;10]
t = 0:0.5:10;
y = ode(y0,0,t,f)
plot(t,y)
xtitle("Mass-Spring","T length","Y mass");
```

The result's graph:
[image]

Can you help me? cause I think my code is not complete

Comment: Where are you defining f?

Comment: @Ian it's my function dx=f(t,x)

Comment: I don't see how the first line tells the ODE solver what function to use, unless there is a line further back which defines f.

Comment: @Ian I saw an example on internet where they use a similar code to solve another ODE, in the example code there is not any definition to F like F=something, that's why i think f is related to the function in the first line

Comment: Can you link the example?

Comment: @ian I didn't save the website but this is the original code http://txs.io/QDIb

Comment: Oh, now I see, the first argument just names the thing. OK. So right now what you've written will solve $x'=t$, which is not what you want. Your equation is second order, so you probably want to encode it as two first order equations, specifically something along the lines of $x'=y,y'=(-k/m)x$. I don't know enough about scilab to tell you how to write the deff line so as to define a vector-valued function of a vector variable.

Comment: @Ian yeah I'm new to scilab too, I don't know how to define a second order equation either, I'll try to find it, thanks

Comment: I took a quick look at the tutorial; you can proceed without using deff as a shortcut, but instead making an actual function. function dx=f(t,x) dx(1)=x(2); dx(2)=-k/m*x(1); endfunction <--- something like this should work

Comment: @Ian For what you are using the parenthesis  dx(1), -k/m*x(1) etc

Comment: x (1) is the first component of the vector x.

Comment: @Ian hi again, finally I could finish the script http://txs.io/FNIb, can you take a look to see if is right, and this is the graphic that gave me http://i.imgur.com/L9UuGnA.jpg 
and the scilab ode docu https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.2/en_US/ode.html

Answer (score 2):

The sign of `ydot(2)` is wrong in the original code there should be a minus:

```
function ydot=f(t, y)
    k=1
    m=1
    ydot(1) = y(2);
    ydot(2) = -k/m*y(1);
endfunction
y0 = [10;10]
t = 0:0.5:10;
y = ode(y0,0,t,f)
plot(t,y)
xtitle("Mass-Spring","T length","Y mass");
```

it yields the following graph:
[image]